# Cisco 3850 Model Naming Convention?

Tags: cisco, switch, hardware

I am having some trouble identifying a switch model via the CLI, and also understanding the differences between a few different models.

The models in question are :

- 3850-48P-S
- 3850-48P-L
- 3850-48P-E

Any 'show version' or 'show hardware' command I use only shows 3850-48P and not the suffixes S, L or E that Cisco has on their website. Where in the world can I compare these models to see the difference? Additionally, how can I find what model my switch is via the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reporting your hardware. The letter to which you refer is the license, which can be updated.

- L is for the LAN Base license
- S is for the IP Base License
- E is for the IP Services license

The letter is really only significant when you order the device because you can change the license, but the hardware doesn't change.

Comment: Great! Is there anywhere that has a concise explanation of some of Cisco's crazy naming conventions?

Comment: Cisco explains it on its web site.

Comment: I figured as much. Do you know where?

Comment: All over the place. For example, the 3850 Data Sheet has ordering information that explains it. The CCW gives you the description, too.